# difference between a valve and a filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Can someone explain the difference between a servlet filter and tomcat valve. What is the advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: Sometimes you need a Valve to do Tomcat-specific stuff, for example SSL acceleration behind a Netscaler. See http://blog.inuus.com/vox/2009/04/tomcat-and-ssl-accelerators.html.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From Tomcat documentation:

> A Valve element represents a component that will be inserted into the request processing pipeline for the associated Catalina container

The servlet filters serve the exact same purpose, but valves are Tomcat's specific classes, tightly coupled to Tomcat infrastructure/API. On the other hand servlet API is implemented by all compatible web containers. That said, valves won't work with e.g. Jetty, which has different API for that, while servlet filters will.

The other important difference is that valves are working on container level (intercepting all applications/requests), while servlet filters are intercepting all request only to a given application. So if you want to implement server-wide interceptor, valves are necessary.

Comment: When deploying web applications inside a application server (such as jboss) I should use a filter for doing things specific to a webapp and not a valve?

Comment: I would even say: you should **always** use servlet filter, unless you really need a valve (look for instance at [Logback Access](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html) to see when valve is needed).

Comment: I believe that you are incorrect in saying that a filter are intercepting all requests only to a given application. The tomcat documentation says: "Tomcat provides a number of Filters which may be configured for use with all web applications using $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml or may be configured for individual web applications by configuring them in the application's WEB-INF/web.xml. Each filter is described below."

A filter can be configured for use with all applications.

Answer (score 11):

Valves are tomcat-specific. Filters are standard and their behaviour is defined by the specification. In most cases you would want a filter.

Valves are to be used only for functionalities that requrie access to native-tomcat APIs. Which is rather rare.

Comment: What should I use if I want to add log statements to find out how long it takes for each HTTP request to be processed?

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly right. With filters you can affect some pieces of applications, engines or host, with url-pattern. Valves only affect all the pieces of an application, engines or host. Valves have no url-pattern. That´s all.